# Woocommerce Checkout fields jQuery appendTo

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I created new `<div>` elements:

```
jQuery('<div id="es_name" class="form-group row"><label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Naam</label><div id="firstname" class="col-sm-5 firstname"></div><div class="col-sm-5 lastname"></div></div>').appendTo('.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper');
```

Now I want to move the standard #billing_first_name_field into the #es_name div, or if possible even in the #firstname div.

The following code is not working:

```
jQuery("p#billing_first_name_field").appendTo("#es_name");
```

Can somebody help me out?

Markup
[image]

Comment: only first name field?

Comment: At this moment yes.

Comment: at current what happens when you try `jQuery("p#billing_first_name_field").appendTo("#es_name");`

Comment: Nothing changes. The markup as you can see, stays the same.

Comment: Just run this in browser console to check any errors `jQuery("p#billing_first_name_field").appendTo("#es_name");`

Comment: No errors at all.

Comment: If I use `jQuery("#es_name").appendTo("p#billing_first_name_field");` my markup changes. But If I use `jQuery("p#billing_first_name_field").appendTo("#es_name");` it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery("#billing_first_name_field").append("#es_name");

Please check the above solutions.

Comment: This is not the solution. the total div named #billing_first_name_field needs to move/append to inside the #es_name div.